# Exposing JS function to global namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, global

I am trying to make a function available globally. I wrapped it in an immediate function but it only works if I call a `new $MyClass()` inside the function. I want to be able to use it like Jquery, calling functions like this elsewhere in my project:

```
$MyClass('myButton').click(function(){
     console.log('The button was clicked');
});
```

This is what I want access to:

```
   (function() {
      function $MyClass(element){
          element = document.getElementById(element)
          this.element = element;
          return this;
      }

      $MyClass.prototype.click = function(callback) {
          this.element.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
          function clickFunction() {
              callback();
          }
      }

      $MyClass.prototype.hover = function(inEvent, outEvent) {
          this.element.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverOn);

          if (outEvent != undefined) {
              this.element.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOff);
          }
          function hoverOn() {
              inEvent();
          }
          function hoverOff() {
              outEvent();
          }  
      }
}());
```

How do I expose $MyClass to the global namespace? None of the answers I've found online have made sense to me enough to apply it to my project.

Comment: `window.$MyClass = $MyClass`, but you still need a wrapper around your constructor. Check how jQuery does it, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I have studied jquery's source and tried to mimic it with no luck, so i was hoping someone could give simpler example here.  I'm a js beginner and still trying to make sense of the basics.

Comment: What's the reason to wrap it in an IIFE in the first place? Usually you do this to avoid exposing your stuff to the global namespace. And what's your motivation to write this class?

Comment: A learning exercise. I want to know how to do it, that's all.